# Java: Why can't I cast this to an Object?

Tags: java, object, casting

This is bizarre... I thought every object in java had Object as an ancestor.

I have a `ClassA` that extends my `ClassB` and implements `Runnable`.

After creating `ClassA` I cannot cast it to an `Object`.

Assume `getClassA` returns a `ClassA` instance.

I am doing

```
Object obj = getClassA();
```

I also tried

```
Object obj = (Object) getClassA();
```

I get an incompatible types compile error: found Class, required Object.

What's the deal with that?  I thought all objects could be cast to Object.

Edit: I assume it has something to do with the fact that ClassA implements Runnable, but I am not sure and need an explanation.

Edit2: Changing getClassA() to return an Object allows the program to compile.

Edit3: Importing the package that contained ClassB fixed the problem.  Class B was defined in a different jar.  ClassA was defined in another jar that referenced the jar containing ClassB.

Comment: Show the getClassA() implementation and signature.

Comment: Please show the body (not just the signature) of `getClassA()`. It seems that the error is inside the body, not at the point where you call it.

Comment: public static ClassA getClassA(String a, String b); public class ClassA extends AnotherClass implements Runnable; Sorry I cannot post implementation

Comment: Then there's not much that can be done. The line that you have posted clearly cannot produce such an error message, under any conditions. So the error message comes from a different line. If you cannot post that, then there's no way to tell why it's wrong.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that error message is "found Class, required Object", and not e.g. "found ClassA, required Object"?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am also getting this somewhere else. It could be an issue with the IDE

Comment: In my case, it was indeed a problem with Netbeans. The code compiles fine from command line. (I am referring to a different code of course)

Answer (score 6):

Do you by chance have a class named `Object` somewhere in your code (or non-standard packages that it imports)?

Comment: if so, try the cast as - java.lang.Object obj = getClassA();

Answer (score 2):

How you are compiling the java file. Can you give some more information about getClassA(). What is the return type of this method?

The type casting is unnecessary since all objects in java are of type Object.

If you are using a IDE like eclipse you can put a break point on the line where you are assigning the Object obj = getClassA(); and inspect the value returned by getClassA().

Else you can try to put a instanceof condition before assigning the value to obj.

```
if(getClassA() instanceof Object){
    Object obj = getClassA();
}else{
    System.out.println("getClassA() is not retuning an object: "+ getClassA());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class does descend from Object.  There's something else going on here.

If you're code really is:

```
//...Code
Object obj = MyObject.getClassA();
//More Code...

class MyObject{
  static Class getClassA(){...}
}
```

It should work.  Show us the code for an actual answer.

Comment: public static ClassA getClassA(String a, String b);

public class ClassA extends AnotherClass implements Runnable;

Sorry I cannot post implementation

Answer (score -4):

I tried this in Eclipse and got an "unnecessary cast" warning. You can probably configure it so that is an error instead of a warning, so I would guess that's what you did.

Comment: This answers the error you were encountering, not the error the person asking the question was.